# My web page ends but the scroll keeps going

Tags: html, css

I have developed a simple web page for an assignment. All is good but at the point where my page virtually ends, I mean at the last line of content, the scrollbar keeps on going for almost another 70% of my page length to the bottom and there is nothing visible except the background. Have I added sometething that would cause this? Do you have any suggestions?

Here is the css code:

```
#wrapper {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
/** background CSS **/
body{
    background-image:url('bg.png');

}
#header{
    position:relative;
    left:23%;
}

#menu{
    position: relative;
    top:-5px;
    left:24.2%;
    word-spacing:60px;
}

#list1{
    display: inline;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial Black;
    font-size:25px;
    padding:6px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px;
    background-color: #cc0300;
    color: #ffffff;


    }

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

#list1:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;

}

#news{  
    position:relative;
    left:25%;
}


#whtspc{
    position:relative;
    right:41px;
    top:70px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 15px 15px;

}
/** background CSS **/

/** header for content section **/
#shead{
    position:relative;
    top:-1490px;
    font-size:30px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial Black;
    color:#ffffff;

}
#n{
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 3px 3px;
    background-color: #ff6600;
    padding: 6px;
}
/** header for content section **/

/** content **/

#h1{
    position:relative;
    top:-1480px;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial Black;
    color:#000000;
}

#goty{
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    width:240px;
    float:left;
    top:-1480px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    border-radius:3px 3px;
}
#c1{
    position:relative;
    top:-1470px;
    left:10px;
    font-size:15px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial Black;
    color:#000000;
}
table{
    position:relative;
    top:-1460px;
    left:10px;
    font-size:15px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial Black;
    color:#000000;
    background-color:black;
    width:30%;
    border-radius: 3px 3px;
}
#tr1{
    background-color: #ff6600;
}
#tr2{
    background-color: #ff6600;
    color:#ffffff;
}

#hr1{
    position:relative;
    top:-1440px;
    float:left;
    left:150px;
    }

#h2{
    position:relative;
    top:-1386px;
    left:-608px;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial Black;
    color:#000000;
}

#cons{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    top:-1365px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    border-radius:3px 3px;
}


#c2{    
    position:relative;
    top:-1355px;
    left:10px;
    font-size:15px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial Black;
    color:#000000;
}

#hr2{
    position:relative;
    top:-1310px;
    left:-482px;
}
#h3{
    position:relative;
    top:-1296px;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial Black;
    color:#000000;
}
#oc{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    top:-1265px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    border-radius:3px 3px;
}

#c3{
    position:relative;
    top:-1265px;
    left:10px;
    font-size:15px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial Black;
    color:#000000;
}

#hr3{
    position:relative;
    top:-1270px;
    left:-485px;
}
```

Comment: Please include the code, it'll likely be a CSS issue.

Comment: Show your code .How can we answer without any clue of what you have done

Comment: recreate it in a fiddle

Comment: Try to narrow the code down. Leave out the big blocks of content, and include the minimal amount of code that will reproduce the issue.

Comment: Added the code. What I noticed was that as I was adding content, the scroll kept getting bigger without the size of the site changing.

Comment: this isn't going to help, you should post a link or recreate the issue somewhere for us to test

Comment: here is the html code http://pastebin.com/DTsnXKMa 
It's in Greek, I'm sorry.

Comment: In your html, the `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="home.css"/>` should be inside the `head` tag.

Comment: What's with all the odd top spacings? Like `top:-1365px;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are using `position:relative` and oddly moving all of the elements off screen. I have no idea why you're doing that but if you kill all of those properties you can see the content fills the page just fine

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aWx3k/1/)